# Optimisation Required to extract pair of numbers from two different sets following a condition?

Tags: c++, performance, dictionary, stl

I have to two vectors of type

```
      typedef long long LL  ;

      vector < LL > store1 , store2 ;
```

The size of each vector <= 20000.
Now I need to extract all such pairs ( one element from store1 and one element from store2 ) such that

```
      gcd ( element1 ,element2 ) != 1 ;
```

Each element from either store is used exactly once to form a pair.

The approach that I am currently using is very slow.
My approach ;

```
     ll gcd(ll a, ll b) { return (b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b)); }

     vector < LL > :: iterator it , fit ;
     LL ans = 0 ;         
           // count of pairs
     for ( it = store1.begin() ; it != store1.end() ; it++)
     {
           LL x = (*it) ;

           for( fit = store2.begin() ; fit != store2.end() ; fit++){

              LL y = (*fit) ;
              if ( gcd(x,y) != 1){

                   ans++ ;
                   store2.erase(fit); break ;
              }   

           }
      }
```

Time Limit : 1s
All numbers are <= 10^9

I am using 64-bit integer type to avoid any kind of overflow.

A you can see that there cannot be more than 20000 such pairs. I am following a O(n**2) approach which is too slow for my application.

Late Edit :
I want to know if there is a certain property of gcd through which extraction of pairs becomes faster. Application of concepts of Number Theory which can be used to decrease complexity.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the range of numbers stored?  It looks like they're 64-bit ints, but in practice do they take up that entire space?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the posted routine is very slow (except if there are performance issues in the gcd() function).  It just doesn't match with the given requirements of returning all matching couples. All it does per entry of the first map is looking for the first match, incrementing a counter, removing the matching entry in the second map.  Getting all matches involves iterating each combination and adding the match to a result container.

Comment: @stefaanv The Gcd function used is standard euclid method.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I have edited my question and mentioned the constraints.

Comment: But more importantly, am I correct that the code and the requirements don't match?

Comment: @stefaanv I failed to mention that each element is used only once from each store to form a pair.

Comment: You could try putting the data in a vector as a class, using custom operator < to sort only by the first two values (the keys), and using `std::binary_search`. Vector has better memory locality, and COULD be faster.

Comment: Your current code doesn't use `P` or `first` at all.  Can you simplify your code to get rid of the `std::pair` then, at least for this discussion?

Comment: @JohnZwinck actually the map were used for previous operations. The question I asked is only the final step. Sorry I'll edit my code right now.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I have edited my code please take a look.

Comment: @stefaanv I have run on both versions for store sizes of 6000 each .. Vector version takes 1.18s while map version takes 1.29s.

Comment: It seems to me that your algorithm design is O(n**2). No way around that. What problem are you *really* trying to solve?

Comment: @RichardHodges This is a part of my approach towards an ongoing contest. Link : http://www.codechef.com/JULY14/problems/GNUM

Comment: @RichardHodges I don't want to urge you to give me the full solution, I was just wondering if my approach could be optimised. Currently I am getting Time Limit Exceeded.

Comment: @AmitKumar I am suggesting that you re-think the problem. If your algorithm has On^2 complexity in the long run, no amount of optimisation will help you. 
In the short term, you could easily parallelise the algorithm by dividing store2 across all available cores.

Comment: @RichardHodges Thanks for the suggestion but I have no idea of parallel programming. I would look for an alternative approach.

Comment: @RichardHodges I was wondering if concepts of number theory could help.

Comment: @AmitKumar Thanks for the results.  Nice to know that there actually was an optimisation, too bad that it's not enough.